# Codeigniter: Foreach to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I have this error in CI:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: loai
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57
```

My controller:

```
public function loaibds() 
        {    
             $this->load->model('admin_model');
             $data['loai'] = $this->admin_model->loai();
             $this->load->view('thembds', $data);        
        }
```

My Model:

```
public function loai()
            {
                 $l = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM loaibds");

                 if($l->num_rows() > 0)
                     return $l->result();
                 return false;
            }
```

My View:

```
<select class="form-control" name="loai">
 <?php foreach($loai as $l) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $l->id; ?>"> <?php echo $l->loai; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>  
  </select>
```

What mistake do I have?  I want to assign the rows and echo out on the view page e.g

Comment: just check `var_dump($data)` from the controller, see if its empty

Answer (score 2):

```
             $l = $this->db->get('loaibds')->result();

             if($l->num_rows() > 0)
                 return $l;
           }
```

Comment: use this in your loai function

Comment: My result: 
                                            

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: loai
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57



A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57

Comment: did you add $this->load->modal('Model_name') on your controller __construct funtion

Answer (score 0):

Because `$l->result()` is a resource, not a result.

Change the model to the following:

```
public function loai()
        {
             $l = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM loaibds");

             $result = array();
             if($l->num_rows() > 0)
                   foreach ($l->result() as $row)
                       $result = $row;
             return $result;
        }
```

It should work now.

Comment: My result:                                            

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: loai
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57



A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/thembds.php
Line Number: 57

Comment: can you show the output of `var_dump($data)` before you load the view please?

Comment: var_dump($data) RESULT: array(1) { ["loai"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["loai"]=> string(9) "Cho thuÃª" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["loai"]=> string(10) "Cáº§n bÃ¡n" } } }

Comment: It has classes as objects not objects. This is the reason why your loai object is not passed to the view. retrieve the data, put them in an associative array and then pass it to the view to render.

Answer (score 0):

change your model

```
$l = $this->db->get('loaibds');
if($l->num_rows()>0)
{
   return $l->result();
}
else{

    return FALSE;
}
```